# How to test if a string is a substring of any instance of a regex?

Tags: regex, substring, instance

In any programming language and library,

How can you test if a string is a substring of any instance of a regular expression?

For example, all the instances of the regex

```
RA = /^a{1,2}c{1,2}$/
```

are

```
'ac', 'acc', 'aac', 'aacc'.
```

The string 'cc' is not an instance of the regex but is a substring of two instances of the regex. How can you test that 'c' has such a property?

Equivalently, how can you get (in general) a regex whose instances are all substrings of any instances of another regex.

For the example above, the regex

```
RB = /^a{0,2}c{0,2}$/
```

has the instances

```
'', 'c', 'cc', 'a', 'ac', 'acc', 'aa', 'aac', 'aacc'
```

which are all the substrings of the instances of RA.

How can you calculate such a RB from RA for any regex RA?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean a regular expression as defined by computer science, or an (ir)regular expression as implemented by most modern languages? If you mean the latter, which language in particular is most interesting for you?

Comment: I'm most interested in an implementation in C++ but any other programming language is fine

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a computer science regular expression, you can do this by forming an alternation of all subsequences of tokens:

```
/^a{1,2}c{1,2}$/ -> /^(a{1,2}|a{1,2}c{1,2}|c{1,2}|)$/
```

Note that will grow in length as O(n<sup>2</sup>) where n is the number tokens in the original expression.

Comment: OK, this is a really good answer. But do you know a regex library that implements that kind of alternation? If not, what free library would you choose to modify and implement it?

Comment: I have never heard of any library that implements this, and I suspect that it will be quite difficult to implement it correctly for the general case - especially if performance is an issue. I guess if you could convert the regular expression into its corresponding finite state machine you could get a more efficient solution, but that's also a lot more work.